# Get array of elements from event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have few nested DIV elements. For example:

```
<div id='id1'><div id='id2'>content</div></div>
```

I attach event to DIVs event handler using jQuery:

```
$('div').click(function () {
    //some code   
});
```

There will be two events when user click on content. So there will be two simultaneous events. Is it possible to get inside event handler array of objects (DIVs) what have click event?

May be it is possible using other framework but jQuery?

Comment: Your question is a little vague. Are you asking how to get a list of all the elements in the DOM which have a click event handler attached?

Comment: please clarify your question. Do you want to attach event handlers to the innermost div only, or find out all divs that have a click handler attached?

Comment: So you want to get an array of ALL the divs whose children are being clicked on?

Comment: When user click on inner DIV element two events fired (click event for first DIV and click for second DIV). I want get an array in this case [DIV1, DIV2].

Comment: @Anton - My answer gives the array you want, although I used `e.stopPropagation()` so it is only effective for the innermost `div`. You can remove that line if needed.

Comment: @Anton - You want to get this on the child or the parent, and should it only be children, those with the handler, or every element in the chain?  It's a very ambiguous question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you literally want an array of the `div` objects that would get the click event, you could do:

```
$('div').click(function(e) {
    var array = $(e.target).parents('div').andSelf().get();
    alert(array);
    e.stopPropagation();;
});
```

Not sure if that's what you want, but `array` will contain an array of `div`s up the chain.

Answer (score 0):

If you do this, then the outer handler won't fire when the inner div is clicked:

```
$('div').click(function () {
    //some code

    return false;  
});
```

If you want to get an array of ALL the divs being clicked on, use this:

```
$('div').click(function () {
    //some code
    var divs = $(this).parents('div'); //Gets all the divs which are ancestors

    return false; //Prevent event bubbling 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you handler is like the question:

```
$('div').click(function () {
    //some code   
});
```

You can get the divs inside like this:

```
$('div').click(function () {
    $(this).find("div") //do something
});
```